# How do you run an ActiveX control with .NET 2.0 dependencies in .NET4?

Tags: .net-4.0, .net-2.0, activex

I have an C# ActiveX Control that has dependencies on .NET 2.0 (i.e. the Visual Studio project has the Target Framework set to .NET Framework 2.0).  The control runs fine if the .NET 2.0 framework is present on the the browser machine; but does not work if .NET2.0 is not installed.  I'd like this control to also work if .NET 4.0 is installed on the browser machine.

How can you configure an ActiveX control/dll targeted to .NET 2.0 to also run if .NET4 is installed instead?